# Determine if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5^{n+1}}{(3n-2)!}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Determine if the following series is convergent:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5^{n+1}}{(3n-2)!}$$

so we have
$$u_n=\frac{5^{n+1}}{(3n-2)!}$$ 
$$u_{n+1}=\frac{5^{n+2}}{(3n+1)!}.$$

With the ratio test: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{5^{n+2}}{(3n+1)!}\frac{(3n-2)!}{5^{n+1}} $$

and I'm stuck here now. I'm pretty sure I have to do something with the factorials, but I don't know what to do since the factorial expression has a negative constant in it.
$$(3n-2)!=??$$

Thank you for the help!

Comment: $$(3n+1)!=(3n+1)3n(3n-1)\cdot(3n-2)!$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ratio test you get $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\frac{5}{\left(3n+1\right)3n\left(3n-1\right)}\rightarrow0
 $$ so the series converges. Maybe it is interesting to note that we can find the (ugly) closed form of this series. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795437/series-fracx3n3n-find-sum-using-differentiation/1795490#1795490) is proved that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n\right)!}=\frac{2}{3}e^{-x/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)+\frac{e^{x}}{3}-1
 $$ so if we differentiate twice we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{3n-2}}{\left(3n-2\right)!}=\frac{e^{x}}{3}+\frac{e^{-x/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-x/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)
 $$ so $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n-2\right)!}=x^{2}\left(\frac{e^{x}}{3}+\frac{e^{-x/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-x/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)\right)
 $$ then if we take $x=\sqrt[3]{5}
 $ we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{5^{n}}{\left(3n-2\right)!}=5^{2/3}\left(\frac{e^{5^{1/3}}}{3}+\frac{e^{-x/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}5^{1/3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-5^{1/3}/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}5^{1/3}\right)\right)
 $$ so finally $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{5^{n+1}}{\left(3n-2\right)!}=\color{red}{5^{5/3}\left(\frac{e^{5^{1/3}}}{3}+\frac{e^{-x/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}5^{1/3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-5^{1/3}/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}5^{1/3}\right)\right).}$$

Answer (score 3):

An other way without ratio test :

$\forall n \geq1, 3n-1 \geq n$, so $(3n-1)!\geq n!$, so : $$\frac{5^{n+1}}{(3n-2)!}\le5\frac{5^{n}}{n!}$$
And the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 5\frac{5^{n}}{n!}$ is convergent (it is $5(e^5-1)$).
So by comparison of positives series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5^{n+1}}{(3n-2)!}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing that \begin{align}(3n + 1)! &= (3n + 1)(3n + 0)(3n - 1)(3n - 2)(3n - 3)(3n - 4)\ldots\\ &= (3n + 1)(3n)(3n - 1)(3n - 2)!\end{align} for sufficiently large $n$, the factorial terms cancel, giving the ratio as \begin{equation}\frac{5}{27n^3-3n}.\end{equation} Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ of course gives $0$, thus satisfying the condition for convergence.

Comment: Sorry, was in a rush on my phone. Edited it for the explicit expression.

Answer (score 1):

By comparison: $(3n-2)!\ge n!$ for all positive $n$, hence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^{n+1}}{(3n-2)!}\le5\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5^n}{n!}=5(e^5-1). $$